# Issues with reading numbers from serial port

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I've built 2 motor drivers for a robotics project and need to set positions that I want the motors to move to, and read that using the arduino. The arduino then uses a rotary encoder to implement a closed loop PID controller and move the motor the set point. My code wasn't working so I started troubleshooting and found out that my setpoint was getting reset to 0 automatically!

The only thin that changes the setpoint was the serial read so I made a smaller sketch for troubleshooting which is this:

```
volatile long setpoint;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()){
    setpoint = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("Set to: ");
    Serial.println(setpoint);
  }
}
```

The result was quite odd, it sets the value correctly but resets back to 0 without me sending any new commands!

I tried updating the IDE to 1.8.12, tried old and new arduinos (with old and new bootloader) but all had the same result. Here is a demo video showing the weird reset to 0 problem:

https://streamable.com/kfgv61

I tried changing the buadrate higher or lower but that also didn't fix anything. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Serial.parseInt()` stops when it sees the
newline, but *it does not consume that newline*, which is left in the
input buffer. Thus, at the next loop iteration, `Serial.available()`
returns true because of this newline and, unless you send another value
fast enough, `Serial.parseInt()` times out and returns zero.

The easy fix is to consume that newline yourself:

```cpp
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()){
    setpoint = Serial.parseInt();
    if (Serial.peek() == '\n') Serial.read();  // consume LF
    Serial.print("Set to: ");
    Serial.println(setpoint);
  }
}
```

I personally would not use `Serial.parseInt()` at all, and would [buffer
the data myself](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino) until I see the `'\n'`. This way there are
no surprises with timeouts being read as zero.